# Java Threads within Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executor

I have an application that inserts header and detail data into database tables (2 tables 1 for header info and 1 for detail info). My current approach is to distribute the details equally in my threads. The header will contain an average of 100,000 details.

I want to change my approach to handle multiple headers. I will encapsulate the logic of 1 header in a function (this function will contain multithreading for its details) and call this function in several threads (the number of headers) or in a thread pool (using Executors).

Is this the best way to go about it or is there a best practice for such an issue? Also will setting priorities for the threads affect the flow of the threads? (I will set higher priorities for the headers and keep the default for the details)

Comment: Do you think you're getting an advantage from multithreading? Is there enough CPU work to do to deserve multiple threads? Sounds like a single threaded approach would be simpler and more efficient here. Setting priorities to threads is unlikely to give you any advantage either.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that each header will contain an average of 100,000 details. My current approach for one header has already improved performance for me.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need multithreading if you're just inserting data into the DB. Is there CPU work to be done? Are you inserting the data properly in batches?

Comment: Yes there is, my data is the result of unmarshalling an xml, there are some business rules that I need to apply to the result objects first then I insert the data into their respective tables, also I have several db calls at different stages and calling a shell file.

Comment: Well, first of all you *should* use executors and other higher level constructs (so no creating own `Thread` classes or fiddling with priorities). I would separate the threads so that you have processing thread(s) and a thread that inserts in the database. Between them a `BlockingQueue` for passing processed data to be inserted into the DB. This way you can test where additional threads are useful (in the processing phase) and where they're less useful (in the DB insertion phase), and adjust the executor sizes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the nature of the problem you described, it is likely that the main bottleneck of the application is going to be database I/O. That should be addressed first. Some common practices:

- consider the granularity of your database transactions: you will achieve better performance if you group multiple details inserts in a transaction than if you insert details one at time (as would happen in autocommit mode)
- use and tune a database connection pool, so you can have multiple threads performing database operations concurrently while not taxing the database server too much.
- remember that DB operations are mostly I/O-bound, so you can probably use more threads than you have cores
- whenever applicable, use an `ExecutorService` instead of creating your own threads, so you don't have to manage the threads' life cycle yourself